# Integration of jolokia & getting details of cordapps and flows inside apps using jolokia

Tags: corda

We have some queries related to metrics from corda and cordapps:

1. How are metrics propagated from Corda Core to Jolokia?
2. The link https://docs.corda.net/design/monitoring-management/design.html shows a number of metrics. But we are not sure how to get those metrics using Jolokia agent. We got the list of metrics when we did a list, but many of the metrics were missing in the list.
3. Suppose a CorDapp developer needs to expose some app-specific Corda metrics. How can we capture app level metrics? How to associate a metrics to a specific cordapp? How to integrate Jolokia with cordapp?

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3.2:

1. The list of exported metrics is documented here: https://docs.corda.net/node-administration.html#monitoring-your-node. The metrics are propagated from the node to Jolokia using the `MonitoringService` registered with the `ServiceHubInternal`
2. This is a design document, and does not reflect the current state of monitoring in Corda
3. Currently, CorDapps cannot expose their own metrics. `MonitoringService` is only registered on `ServiceHubInternal` rather than on the `ServiceHub`, so it is not accessible to CorDapp developers. Allowing CorDapps to expose their own metrics will be a future feature